# Convert Object to JSON string only Serialized fields

Tags: c#, json, serialization

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON =  serializer.Serialize(pt);
```

This works fine except that it also includes fields that are set as `[NonSerialized]`
Is there a way to exclude those fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[ScriptIgnore()]` is what you want

the `[NonSerialized()]` tag works only for binary serilaization, your example is one of Java script serialization

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the [`ScriptIgnoreAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx):

```
public class Data {

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public string Ignore;

    public string DoNotIgnore;
}
```